# GET .json from Helpscout API using Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm a newbie to Python API, and wanted to obtain the json object "Conversation thread" from Helpscout, following their [developer API documentation](http://developer.helpscout.net/conversations/get/).

I attempted `requests.get("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/{id}.json")` (I replaced the id with an actual conversation) but that returns a 401 error.

Helpscout gives out a API_KEY which I need to somehow pass it to the requests. How do I go about doing it?

Thanks!

```
In [23]: requests.get("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/10532436.json")
Out[23]: <Response [401]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your API KEY in there... use: `requests.get("https://api.helpscout.net/v1/conversations/{id}.json", auth=('{API_KEY}','X'))` and of course replace the API_KEY with the one you got from helpscout.

Comment: Amazingly quick! Works like magic. Question - where can i find that it's looking for the "X" as the second item in the tuple for the credentials?

Comment: The 'X' really doesn't matter. You can put anything you want in there. Helpscout only looks at the first item as their API KEY. They don't care about the second item, but it needs to be there.